# Plotly: Hide date in axis ticks but show in hoverlabel title created with `x unified`

Tags: python, formatting, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

In the axis ticklabels, I want to show only the month and the year (grouped), like this -

[image]

But that also means I have to sacrifice on the day of the date (1-31) in the hoverlabel title. Is there a way I can hide the day part of the date on the axis (with grouped years and short month) and yet see it on the hoverlabel title? Something like this but without the `01`s before each month on the axis.

[image]

Here's the code to reproduce the graph-

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y=['GOOG','AAPL'])
fig.update_layout(hovermode='x unified', xaxis_title=None, yaxis_title=None, xaxis_tickformat='%d%b\n%Y',
                 hoverlabel=dict(namelength=0))
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate=None)
# fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='%{x|%d%b,%Y} value: %{y:.2f}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the parameter `xaxis_hoverformat` in the `update_layout` method. In this case, you don't need to use a hovertemplate.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y=['GOOG','AAPL'])
fig.update_layout(
    hovermode='x unified', 
    xaxis_title=None, 
    yaxis_title=None, 
    xaxis_tickformat='%b\n%Y',
    xaxis_hoverformat='%d%b,%Y',
    hoverlabel=dict(namelength=0)
)

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate=None)
fig.show()
```

[image]